# Group to Group division

Tags: r, dataframe

Data Set:

```
  date     bal      
1/31/2013  10   
1/31/2013  11  
1/31/2013  12  
1/31/2013  13   
1/31/2013  14 
2/28/2013  20   
2/28/2013  30  
2/28/2013  40  
2/28/2013  50   
2/28/2013  60    
3/30/2013  10  
3/30/2013  11     
3/30/2013  12   
3/30/2013  13    
3/30/2013  15
```

Code used:

```
bb <- read.csv("abc.csv", stringsAsFactors=T, header=T)
bb
library(dplyr)

new_data <- bb %>% 
   mutate(D = (bal) / lag(bal[1:5])) %>%
   data.frame()
new_data
```

We are dividing group 2 (dates - 2/28/2013's second row = 30) / (group 1 - 1/31/2013's first row = 10)
that is: 30 / 10 = 3.000, 40/11 = 3.63, 50/12 = 4.16 and so on.

Output got from the above code:

```
     date     bal        D
1   1/31/2013  10       NA
2   1/31/2013  11 1.100000
3   1/31/2013  12 1.090909
4   1/31/2013  13 1.083333
5   1/31/2013  14 1.076923
6   2/28/2013  20       NA
7   2/28/2013  30 3.000000
8   2/28/2013  40 3.636364
9   2/28/2013  50 4.166667
10  2/28/2013  60 4.615385
11  3/30/2013  10       NA
12  3/30/2013  11 1.100000
13  3/30/2013  12 1.090909
14  3/30/2013  13 1.083333
15  3/30/2013  15 1.153846
```

Now the problem here is:

The first group is kept as the reference = Divisor, that 10, 11,12,13
that means all the below groups of dates(bal) are getting divided by the first reference group.

We want that each time the divisor should increment by next group date and same with the below group (dividend) as so on.

```
     date     bal        D           
1   1/31/2013  10       NA         
2   1/31/2013  11       NA
3   1/31/2013  12       NA  
4   1/31/2013  13       NA 
5   1/31/2013  14       NA
6   2/28/2013  20       NA
7   2/28/2013  30 3.000000       - 30 / 10 = 3
8   2/28/2013  40 3.636364       - 40 / 11 = 3.63  
9   2/28/2013  50 4.166667       - 50 / 12 = 4.16
10  2/28/2013  60 4.615385       - 60 / 13 = 4.61
11  3/30/2013  10       NA          NA
12  3/30/2013  11 1.100000       - 11 / 20 = 0.55 
13  3/30/2013  12 1.090909       - 12 / 30 = 0.4
14  3/30/2013  13 1.083333       - 13 / 40 = 0.325 
15  3/30/2013  15 1.153846       - 15 / 50 = 0.3
```

I'm  expecting the above output.

Comment: So the first entry of date Y should be divided by the first entry of date X (the one before Y)? Is that the logic here?

Comment: considering Y[1] = 1/31/2013, bal = 10, and X[2] = 2/28/2013, bal = 30, so we need divide - X[2] / Y[1] and so on. similary for the below same logic should be applied.

Comment: are you always going to have same number of rows for each date? (i.e. in this case all are 5)

Comment: yes, same number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DF %>%
  group_by(g1=seq_along(bal) %% 5) %>%
  mutate(denominator=lag(bal)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(g2=(seq_along(bal) - 1) %/% 5) %>%
  mutate(denominator=lag(denominator),
         D=bal / denominator) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 15 x 6
#         date   bal    g1 denominator    g2        D
#       <fctr> <int> <dbl>       <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 1/31/2013    10     1          NA     0       NA
#  2 1/31/2013    11     2          NA     0       NA
#  3 1/31/2013    12     3          NA     0       NA
#  4 1/31/2013    13     4          NA     0       NA
#  5 1/31/2013    14     0          NA     0       NA
#  6 2/28/2013    20     1          NA     1       NA
#  7 2/28/2013    30     2          10     1 3.000000
#  8 2/28/2013    40     3          11     1 3.636364
#  9 2/28/2013    50     4          12     1 4.166667
# 10 2/28/2013    60     0          13     1 4.615385
# 11 3/30/2013    10     1          NA     2       NA
# 12 3/30/2013    11     2          20     2 0.550000
# 13 3/30/2013    12     3          30     2 0.400000
# 14 3/30/2013    13     4          40     2 0.325000
# 15 3/30/2013    15     0          50     2 0.300000
```

Comment: Perfect. It worked. You are a "GEM" Jason. Thankyou so Much.

Comment: Hi Jason, I have a question, what if at the run time, i got to know that the number of buckets in the above code are changed to 4or 6 rather 5 at this case. So can we make a Generalised Code for this issue??

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: now incase the dates has 5 entries one below the other, in case if the date has 4 or 6 then i have to change the code as per the date's set. Can there be a generalised code which will random take the number date's set. as here is 5.

Comment: If it's either 4 or 6 within the dataset, you can just change the 5 to 4 or 6 right? If it's mixed with 4 and 6 within the dataset, then it will be tricky.

Comment: I need your help on this question as well, i have created a new question, "group multiplication using R", if you can search for this question then please have a look it. I need your expertise on this question:

Answer (score 0):

The OP [has confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591853/group-to-group-division#comment76174247_44591853) that there is always the same number of rows for each date. With this observation, a very simple solution is possible by just lagging the value of `bal` by 6 rows to get the denominator. As this ignores the groups in first place, it is necessary to set the result `D` to NA for the first row in each group, i.e. in every 5th row, finally.

With `data.table`this can be written in a consise "one-liner":

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
setDT(bb)[, D := bal / shift(bal, 6L)][seq(1L, nrow(bb), 5L), D := NA][]
```

which produces the expected result:

```
         date bal        D
 1: 1/31/2013  10       NA
 2: 1/31/2013  11       NA
 3: 1/31/2013  12       NA
 4: 1/31/2013  13       NA
 5: 1/31/2013  14       NA
 6: 2/28/2013  20       NA
 7: 2/28/2013  30 3.000000
 8: 2/28/2013  40 3.636364
 9: 2/28/2013  50 4.166667
10: 2/28/2013  60 4.615385
11: 3/30/2013  10       NA
12: 3/30/2013  11 0.550000
13: 3/30/2013  12 0.400000
14: 3/30/2013  13 0.325000
15: 3/30/2013  15 0.300000
```

Comment: Thanks Uwe. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I need you help, at every 4th and 5th of each group, The Answer should print 100%, That means, for 9th, 10th, 14th and 15th and so on .....  the values under D should be 100.

Comment: @RS. If I understand correctly this is an additional requirement, right?

Comment: no an addition its in the same context. do you want me to create a new question for this :)

Comment: @RS. Yes, that's a good idea. Please, post as a new question. Thank you.